# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed at index 21

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

I get the datetime value as

```
created_at  '2012-02-22T02:06:58.147Z'
Read-only. The time at which this task was created.
```

Which is given by Asana [API](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks)

I am using `Java 8` to parse the date time as following

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

public class Times {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String dateTime = "2012-02-22T02:06:58.147Z";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SX");


    final ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTime, formatter);
    System.out.println(parsed);
  }
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2012-02-22T02:06:58.147Z' could not be parsed at index 21
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1947)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1849)
    at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:597)
    at Times.main(Times.java:11)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

What is not right here?

Comment: You might want to change to "yyyy-M-d' to handle single digit months and days.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The default parser can parse your input. So you don't need a custom formatter and

```
String dateTime = "2012-02-22T02:06:58.147Z";
ZonedDateTime d = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTime);
```

works as expected.

Answer (score 29):

If your input always has a time zone of "zulu" ("Z" = UTC), then you can use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT` (implicitly):

```
final Instant parsed = Instant.parse(dateTime);
```

If time zone varies and has the form of "+01:00" or "+01:00:00" (when not "Z"), then you can use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME;
final ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTime, formatter);
```

If neither is the case, you can construct a `DateTimeFormatter` in the same manner as `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` is constructed.

---

Your current pattern has several problems:

- not using strict mode (`ResolverStyle.STRICT`);
- using `yyyy` instead of `uuuu` (`yyyy` will not work in strict mode);
- using 12-hour `hh` instead of 24-hour `HH`;
- using only one digit `S` for fractional seconds, but input has three.

Comment: Good observation regarding strict or lenient mode! I had originally assumed lenient mode in my answer. For information: Pattern with only one S-symbol instead of ".SSS" is okay in lenient mode.

Comment: Saved by "format "+01:00" or "+01:00:00" (when not "Z"), then you can use  DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME"

Answer (score 2):

Your original problem was wrong pattern symbol "h" which stands for the clock hour (range 1-12). In this case, the am-pm-information is missing. Better, use [the pattern symbol "H"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) instead (hour of day in range 0-23). So the pattern should rather have been like:

uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX (best pattern also suitable for strict mode)

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

public class Times {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String dateTime = "2012-02-22T02:06:58.147Z";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT;
    final ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateTime, formatter.withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
    System.out.println(parsed.toLocalDateTime());
  }
}
```

and gave me output as

```
2012-02-22T02:06:58.147
```

Answer (score 1):

`java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and therefore you do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse a date-time string which is already in ISO 8601 format (e.g. `2012-02-22T02:06:58.147Z`).

### What's wrong with your pattern?

There are two problems with your pattern, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SX`:

1. It has `h` which is used for AM/PM time and therefore it is the wrong symbol for an hour in 24-hour format. The symbol for an hour in 24-hour format is `H`.
2. Your date-time string has a fraction of a second in milliseconds resolution but you have used only one `S`. To match the resolution of milliseconds, the pattern should be `SSS`.

**Demo**:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String strDateTime = "2012-02-22T02:06:58.147Z";
        System.out.println(Instant.parse(strDateTime));
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime));
        System.out.println(OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime));

        // Parsing with your pattern after correction
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
        System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, formatter));
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2012-02-22T02:06:58.147Z
2012-02-22T02:06:58.147Z
2012-02-22T02:06:58.147Z
2012-02-22T02:06:58.147Z
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.