# How to fix error java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-07-24 18:11:33.0' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19

Tags: java, localdatetime

I send the confirmation code link to the e-mail of the registered user, and when the link is clicked, I need to activate the status so that the membership is approved, but I get the error I show in the title. Everything is completely true, but I can't understand why this happened. This is my code:

1)In this code section, the user becomes a member and a confirmation code is sent to his e-mail.

```
@WebServlet(name = "RegisterUserSaveController", urlPatterns = {"/register-user-save"})
public class RegisterUserSaveController extends HttpServlet {
    
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            String name = request.getParameter("name");
            String surname = request.getParameter("surname");
            String email = request.getParameter("email");
            String password = request.getParameter("password");
            String repeatPassword = request.getParameter("password-repeat");
            
            if (!password.equals(repeatPassword)) {
                request.setAttribute("error", "Password repeat is not same!");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("register").forward(request, response);
            } else {
                User user = new User();
                user.setName(name);
                user.setSurname(surname);
                user.setEmail(email);
                user.setPassword(PasswordHasher.hashPassword(password));
                String activationCode = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                user.setActivationCode(MD5.hashedMd5(activationCode));
                LocalDateTime expiredDate = LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(1);
                user.setExpiredDate(expiredDate);
                UserDaoService userDaoService = new UserDaoManager();
                userDaoService.save(user);
                
                String subject = "Confirm Registration";
                
                String link = "http://localhost:8084/employee/registerconfirm?code=" + activationCode;
                
                String title = "Your confirmation link:\n " + link;
                
                SendEmail.sendAsync(email, title, subject);
                
                request.setAttribute("info2", "Your Registration was successfully! Pls check your email.");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("success-info").forward(request, response);
            }
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            
        }
```

2)In this code section, the steps after the user clicks on the link sent to the e-mail are performed. So if the code is correct, I validate the user's status column in the database.

```
@WebServlet(name = "RegisterConfirmController", urlPatterns = {"/registerconfirm"})
public class RegisterConfirmController extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String code = request.getParameter("code");
        UserDaoService userDaoService = new UserDaoManager();
        if (code == null) {
            request.setAttribute("info1", "Activation code is not correct!");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("error-info").forward(request, response);
        } else {
            code = MD5.hashedMd5(code);

            User user = userDaoService.findByActivationCode(code);

            if (user == null) {
                request.setAttribute("info1", "Activation code is not correct!");
                request.getRequestDispatcher("error-info").forward(request, response);
            } else {
                LocalDateTime expiredDate = user.getExpiredDate();
                LocalDateTime currentDate = LocalDateTime.now();

                if (expiredDate.isBefore(currentDate)) {
                    request.setAttribute("info1", "Activation code is expired!");
                    request.setAttribute("info2", "resend?id=" + user.getId() + "");
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("error-info").forward(request, response);

                } else if (user.getStatus() == UserStatusEnum.CONFIRMED.getValue()) {

                    request.setAttribute("info1", "Your account already confirmed!");
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("error-info").forward(request, response);

                } else {

                    userDaoService.updateStatusById(user.getId(), UserStatusEnum.CONFIRMED);
                    request.setAttribute("info2", "Your account is confirmed!");
                    request.getRequestDispatcher("success-info").forward(request, response);

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

3)But the problem is that when I click on the link sent to the e-mail, I get the following error.
error java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2021-07-24 18:11:33.0' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 19

4)And this is my method in relation to the database.

```
@Override
    public User findByActivationCode(String activationCode) {
        try (Connection connection = DbConnection.getConnection()) {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select id,expired_date,status from users where activation_code=?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, activationCode);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                User user = new User();
                user.setId(resultSet.getInt(1));
                user.setExpiredDate(LocalDateTime.parse(resultSet.getString(2), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
                user.setStatus(resultSet.getInt(3));
                return user;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("findByActivationCode error " + e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, could you please post the `User` class?

Comment: Might be dattime format error, something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35881775/8601641).

Comment: Also, you possibly should be using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")`

Comment: Good. Please write that up as the answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to decide what to do with the ".0" in the date String returned by resultSet.getString(2).   You could do a substring to remove it.  Or you could change the formatting string to account for it.  I chose ".n" for nanoseconds, but you would have to research what the value means.

Thinking about it a little more, you may not even want to be using resultSet.getString(2).  If this is something coming out of the database, you may want to consider resultSet.getTimestamp(2) which returns a Timestamp.
Information on how to convert it to LocalDateTime can be found here
[How to convert java.sql.timestamp to LocalDate (java8) java.time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23263490/how-to-convert-java-sql-timestamp-to-localdate-java8-java-time)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String text = "2021-07-24 18:11:33.0";
  //
  String text1 = text.substring(0,19);
  LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(text1, 
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
  //
  LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.parse(text, 
  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.n"));

  int ai = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You faced the problem because you have missed the pattern for the *fraction-of-second*. You can use the following pattern:

`u-M-d H:m:s[.[SSSSSSSSS][SSSSSSSS][SSSSSSS][SSSSSS][SSSSS][SSSS][SSS][SS][S]]`

where *fraction-of-second* has been made optional using the square bracket.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                "u-M-d H:m:s[.[SSSSSSSSS][SSSSSSSS][SSSSSSS][SSSSSS][SSSSS][SSSS][SSS][SS][S]]", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String strDateTime = "2021-07-24 18:11:33.0";
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-07-24T18:11:33
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/32kIFW)

I also suggest you change the column type to a Date-Time type which will enable you to use `java.time` types directly instead of dealing with `String`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.